# Regular expression for extracting ASCII figure in Python

Tags: python, regex, ascii

For learning I am trying to find out all occurrence of one given ASCII figure in one bigger text file using regular expression.

input figure is

```
| |
###O
| |
```

Sample bigger input file is

```
  | |                                
  ###O                               
  | |           | |                  
                ###O                 
                | |              | | 
                                 ###O
                                 | |
```

What would be concise regular expression to find out all occurrence of input figure in that big file?

Comment: This is not what regex is for.

Comment: You can't use a regex for that, since ASCII art is irregular :) But to not leave you without any options, if you need to perhaps count all occurences of this satellite (?) then you can either count the heads (`O`), or, when higher accuracy is needed, you can try to parse the ascii art into 2D char array and search neighbouring characters for the rest of the "satellite" parts.

Comment: Yes I know regex may not be good for such things but for fun and learning I wanted to do this using regex also :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how lenient / exact you want your matches to be, the following will generously match thing that look like your ASCII art:

```
(\s+)[|]\s[|]\s*\R+\s*\1###O\s*\R+\s*\1[|]\s[|]
```

[Fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/9mQ9Gh/1)

As it is lenient with the whitespace, it will also match art where the identation gets wonky. If you want to be more strict, this will be hard due to the overlapping lines where one "symbol" ends and the new one begins.  Translating this into a regular expression that will still respect the indentation is something that I have no solution for, as I want to use simple backreferences instead of lookbehind.

Comment: As mentioned in your answer, in cases such as [this one](https://regex101.com/r/1nnXfV/2/) it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

For the given case, the regex that captures it is:

```
 "\s*\| \|\s*###O\s*\| \|"
```

Just count the number of occurrences using the `re` package in Python

Comment: Doesn't work for such cases when the "satellites" are on the same height: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1nnXfV/1)